# Which one is more appropriate? "It'd been/it was in/you were/you'd been in..."

Tags: grammaticality

The full sentence: You were absolutely certain that when you fell asleep, [______] your own bedroom.

Comment: Two of these are grammatically and logically acceptable (though the 'you'd been in ... answer needs rather special context). / A person being their own bedroom needs some rather extreme figurative manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the options you suggested.

> You were absolutely certain that when you fell asleep, **it'd been** your own bedroom.

When you fell asleep, the room in question (*it*) had been (at some point in the past) your own bedroom.  Then you woke up and the timeline had changed or you had inadvertently jumped to a different universe and discovered that it had not ever been your own bedroom.

This one is valid, but it takes some convoluted storytelling to make it reasonable.

> You were absolutely certain that when you fell asleep, **it was in** your own bedroom.

Before going to bed, you were certain that some object previously mentioned (*it*) was in your own bedroom (perhaps rather than the bedroom in which you fell asleep.)

Again, valid, but probably not what you are looking for.

> You were absolutely certain that when you fell asleep, **you were** your own bedroom.

As you drifted in between a conscious and unconscious state, your sleep-deprived brain became convinced that you yourself were your bedroom.

Valid, but you *really* need to get more sleep.

> You were absolutely certain that when you fell asleep, **you'd been in** your own bedroom.

When you went to bed, you thought that you had, at some point, entered your own bedroom.  Upon waking, however, you discovered that it was a sham and the room you'd thought was your own was actually a part of the same soundstage where they filmed the "moon landing".

Valid, but you might want to stock up on tin foil and stay away from microwave ovens.

The sentence you're likely looking for is this one:

> You were absolutely certain that when you fell asleep, **you were *in*** your own bedroom.

You'd been partying pretty hard and stumbled into what you were sure was your room, but when you woke up and saw the three dead bodies and the pile of money, you realized you'd actually gone into the gangster's room next to yours.

Comment: You should post these on reddit.com/writingprompts : in sure they could make quite a few good to read stories out of each of those possibilities — (really hating autocorrect right now: I had to edit the comment four times!)